# I want to change UISegmentedControl images after selection

Tags: ios, image, nsarray, uisegmentedcontrol

I have UISegmentedControl object in which I took images array. Now I want to change this images after selection of each object like UIButton control in which we can set image for selection and also for non selection.
Here is my code

```
NSArray *itemArray;
        itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"grey.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"overlay.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker.png"],
                     nil];

    segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlIndexChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customise segment control with your own images for selected state and normal state in iOS 5
Try this:

```
 UIImage *segmentSelected = 
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_sel.png"] 
    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15)];
 UIImage *segmentUnselected = 
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns.png"] 
    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15)];
 UIImage *segmentSelectedUnselected = 
[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_sel-uns.png"];
  UIImage *segUnselectedSelected = 
[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns-sel.png"];
UIImage *segmentUnselectedUnselected = 
[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns-uns.png"];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected 
forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected 
forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

     [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentUnselectedUnselected 
forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal 
rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal 
barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentSelectedUnselected 
forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected 
rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal 
barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  [[UISegmentedControl appearance] 
setDividerImage:segUnselectedSelected 
forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal 
rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected 
barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

You can also Check Complete UI customisation at               http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5